# workflow replicator activity: how to determine if task was approved or rejected

Tags: sharepoint, workflow

I have basic workflow with replicator activity inside it. Replicator contains my custom sequence activity with standard create task --> ontaskchanged --> complete task sequence.

Now: tasks are created and can be completed without problem. The thing is I cannot find a way to get a value of completed task. Was it approved or rejected ?

Please provide couple lines of code of replicator's ChildCompleted event to get anything out of Sequence activity instance (or any other way).

thanks

**UPDATE:** It seems in order to exchange values between instances of workflow you need to use [DependencyProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). So solution here is: 
1) add DependencyProperty to parent workflow and add property which you will use to store value like this:

```
public static DependencyProperty childStatusProperty = 
System.Workflow.ComponentModel.DependencyProperty.Register("childStatus", 
typeof(string), typeof(parentWorkflowTypeName));

public string childStatus
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)base.GetValue(childStatusProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            base.SetValue(childStatusProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

2) in custom sequence activity access parent's instance and use defined DependencyProperty to set property to value like this:

```
private void completeTask1_MethodInvoking(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var replicator = this.Parent;
        var workflowParent = (parentWorkflowTypeName)replicator.Parent;
        workflowParent.childStatus = "my custom status value";
    }
```

3) read this value using normal property:

```
//from parent workflow
string status = childStatus;
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you have to record somewhere the list of all tasks created. I guess you are creating the tasks in parallel (not sequential). 
I had the same issue, it took me a while to fix this.

Please check this link as a good starting point: http://rmanimaran.wordpress.com/2010/12/02/sharepoint-workflow-replicator-parallel-approval-problem-solution/

Comment: I read that blog post couple times now, but it provides information ONLY how to set values for SequenceActivity instance inside Replicator. I have no problem setting those values. I have a problem how to retrieve RESULT of that SequenceActivity instance. Where to record variable which mean either task was approved or rejected?

Comment: What I did, was in the ChildCompleted keep track of the taskid (that's the item ID of the created approval task). After the replicator completed, I knew one of the tasks was approved or rejected (and only one). I just looped over all approval tasks to find that one task.

Comment: could you provide code how to get taskId out of sequence activity in ChildCompleted event ? I am lost exactly here

Comment: You can do that in the designer of the workflow. You can assign a C# property to the TaskID property. So, open the activity in the designer, go to properties and check TaskID (or something like that).That property is automatically set by SharePoint and you can use that in the ChildCompleted event.